# How do I connect "Sent events" in storyboard to an event handler function in Xcode 13.3 using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I recently updated the OS as well as Xcode version on my macbook, and I'm not sure if I am doing anything wrong. I have only sparingly worked with older version of Xcode and Objective C before.

From a button that I added in storyboard I want to connect the "touch up inside" user event to a function as shown below, but it is not letting me:

[image]

I have tried clicking and dragging from the sent event radio button in storyboard to the function name (as shown above, which worked when connecting this button's referencing output to an IBOutlet variable previously) as well as dragging to the radio button next to the function name, as shown below:

[image]

Nothing happened in both cases and it is not letting me connect the user event to the desired function. Is there anything different I need to do in Xcode 13.3? Is there any way to do this by editing a file rather than using the GUI?

Comment: I think it's Xcode bug, creating new action outlet should work.

Comment: @TusharSharma sorry I don't really know all the terminology in detail. How do I make a "new action outlet"? You mean make a different \@IBOutlet variable? Or is there any way to do this connection by editing a file, instead of using the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, in storyboard, if you click on a button, check the last tab of the inspector if any of the actions are already set up.
2. There might be also a connection issue or an Xcode bug, so I suggest restarting it.
3. There is an another way to hook up Sent Events. Select your button, with CTRL key make the connection to the ViewController icon on top of the screen (see screenshot) and select your desired method.

[image]

If that method does not come up there, it means your Storyboard might be corrupted, or there is a class name mismatch for the View Controller itsef.